# why does showactivated not work (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

My project has a button which when pressed executes the following code:

```
     dim mywin as New MyDialogWindow()
     mywin.showactivated = false
     mywin.show()
```

My dialog window pops up, although showactivated was set to false.
I looked into Microsoft help and found:

```
    Dim window As New AWindow()
    window.ShowActivated = False
    window.Show()
```

My code seems to be the same as Microsoft's code.
Does somebody know what's wrong with showactivated?

EDIT:
I posed this question with code (above) AND behaviour (pop up of my window), which I thought was strange because I erroneously believed that "showactivated" means the window is put into view. Meanwhile I was told the true meaning of showactivated and my question was answered.

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: It works fine.  You need to show us a better repro.  And stop talking about "dialog", it is not a dialog.

Comment: sorry, yes, it's a wpf window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ShowActivated does not hide the Window; it will prevent the Window from receiving focus.

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showactivated(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When a window with its ShowActivated property set to false is opened,
>   the window is not activated and its Activated event is not raised
>   until a user manually activates the window by selecting it. After the
>   window is selected, it activates and deactivates normally.

So the Activated event is not raised. The [Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activated(v=vs.110).aspx) event causes a window to become the foreground window and receive focus.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the dialog window from popping up, ie. not showing but being there? Hide would be "too much". The icon should be in the task bar. Is windowstate.minimized the only solution? Bedankt voor je hulp :)

Comment: From your description (which should be in your question) Minimized is the the correct WindowState. You might want to rethink what you are trying to do; Why open a window when you are minimizing it?

Comment: It's a window which contains details for the user of the main window (a game) where now and then he can "look up" things. In some phase of the game the contents of this "look up window" changes completely so I have to load a new look up window which I would not like to suddenly pop up. But you are right: starting minimized is the correct procedure. Thx.